# ¿Cómo recuperar la siguiente respuesta proveniente de una consulta cUrl API?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Tengo la siguiente respuesta que me da un servidor donde realizo una consulta para verificar unos datos:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 22:02:25 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 514 Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=5 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000 intuit_tid: 5136ee46-1059-4c6b-b445-76ff4973ca9a Set-Cookie: ADRUM_BT=R:0|clientRequestGUID:28245a76-47a6-443d-9f97-2bf9e10f64e147|btId:755; Expires=Fri, 27-Apr-2018 22:02:54 GMT; Path=/ {"var1":"var1", "var2":"var2"}

Ahora bien, el servidor me devuelve un string el cual contiene un encabezado con algunos datos que no me interesan, pero necesito recuperar el json que me devuelve al final de la respuesta.

He utilizado explode() exitosamente para recuperarlo a través del índice del array, pero en el caso de una consulta fallida el explode se comporta de manera inesperada.

hay alguna manera de desechar lo anterior? y dejar solamente el json?

> **Nota**: los datos acá suministrados son a modo de ejemplo, ya que todo
>   se ejecuta en sandbox.

Comment: Puedes añadir como estas utilizando cURL, ya que una de las opciones es para que te devuelva las cabeceras o no.

Comment: Solo estoy colocando esto en el encabezado 'Accept' => 'application/json' y 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', ya que en este caso es lo único que me solicita la Api

Comment: Para el curl, este es el setopt_array, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE, CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headers_req, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST', CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS   => json_encode($body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto el problema,

Solo hacía falta colocar en el setopt_array **CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE**, en ese caso no retorna el header de la respuesta, solo el body que es el json, de ahí solo falta json_decode y queda de lo lindo, gracias a **Xerif** por el indicio.

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro de que lo solucionará. Siento no haber podido responderte antes. Un saludo.