# Obtener datos mediante cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$opciones = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'miurl.com',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{login:usuario,pass:clave}'
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $opciones);

$respuesta  = curl_exec($curl);
$error      = curl_errno($curl);
$errormsg   = curl_error($curl);
$header     = curl_getinfo($curl); 

echo "<b>Error</b>: $error ( $errormsg ) <hr />";
    
var_dump($respuesta); 

curl_close($curl);
```

El resultado que me está devolviendo es un STRING donde veo que, efectivamente está funcionando bien con el código de respuesta:

*"HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2022 10:57:19 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=30 Vary...... Content-Encoding: gzip {DATOSDEMIJSON}"*

Al final de dicho STRING, como podéis ver, veo los datos que me interesan. El problema es que me está devolviendo un STRING y **me interesa que me devuelva un ARRAY con el que poder interactuar correctamente.**

Mil gracias! Un saludo!

Comment: En este enlace de Stackoverflow tienes una respuesta que te puede valer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159967/c%C3%B3mo-recuperar-la-siguiente-respuesta-proveniente-de-una-consulta-curl-api

Comment: Esto: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2022 10:57:19 GMT ...` es el contenido de las cabeceras. Tienes `CURLOPT_HEADER` establecido a `true`, lo cual significa: *quiero las cabeceras* ([ver la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php)), si no las quieres, cámbialo a `false`. Por otra parte, tu manejo de errores es extraño. Deberías verificar con un `if`, pues como está tu código ahora, creas variables para error que, cuando los mismos no ocurran, estarán vacías.

Comment: Adicionalmente a lo que aporta @ACedano Debes analizar (parse) la respuesta. Podrías probar con [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: URLOPT_HEADER => FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php) podrás ver que la opción `CURLOPT_HEADER` sirve para mostrar los encabezados (header), por tanto al tenerla establecida a `true` aquí:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
```

le estás indicando precisamente que te muestre los encabezados en la salida.

Los encabezados son ese contenido que ves antes de los datos:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2022 10:57:19 GMT
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding:
 chunked Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=30 Vary......
 Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Si no lo quieres, establece `CURLOPT_HEADER` a `false`.

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
```

También, en el **Ejemplo 2** del Manual de PHP viene dicho que la opción `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` es obsoleta desde PHP 5.6.0, si tu versión de PHP es superior a esa, debes establecer en tus peticiones cURL esa opción a `false` (en mis pruebas -PHP 7-, me manda las cabeceras si no pongo esa opción en `false`).

También, dado que estás pasando datos por POST, conviene que lo indiques con `CURLOPT_POST`.

Por otra parte, deberías controlar los posibles errores en un condicional, así, puedes aprovechar para crear un objeto con un mensaje de error en ese caso, en lugar de posibles variables vacías.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$opciones = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'miurl.com',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{login:usuario,pass:clave}'
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $opciones);

$respuesta  = curl_exec($curl);

if ( curl_errno($curl) ) {
    $errormsg=sprintf( "<b>Error</b>:%s<hr />",curl_error($curl) );
    $respuesta=json_encode( array( "error"=>$errormsg) );
    //$header = curl_getinfo($curl); ¿¿¿ ???
}

curl_close($curl);

/*
    $json será un objeto con los datos
    o con un mensaje de error en la propiedad error
*/
$json=json_decode($respuesta);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: ¡Genial! Gracias a todos por tomaros la molestia de responder. El mayor problema era CURLOPT_HEADER, ni me percaté de la opción. Al establecerlo en FALSE, automaticamente ya me generó un objeto con el que poder interactuar. Un saludo!