# ¿Cómo solucionar el error que traigo de una api Trying to access array offset on value of type null in?

Tags: php, json

Buen día comunidad.

Estoy consumiendo un servicio de una api y la info que consumo la estoy tratando de insertar a la base de datos mysql, sin embargo me encuentro con este error
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

function obtenerRegistros(){

```
$curl = curl_init();
    $httpheader =array();
    $url = "http://test.com/apiRest";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$httpheader);
    $resultado =curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $ordenes = json_decode($resultado,true);
 
    //Aqui pongo la variable ordenes para acceder al objeto y aqui en esta linea me marca el error
    $ordenes = $ordenes["value"];  
    
  $ordenesTest = array();
     if($ordenes){ 
       foreach($ordenes as $orden){
          foreach($ordenes as $orden){       
                  $no = array(
                'Id' => $orden['Document_ID'],
                'Lugar' => $orden['Sourcing_Location'],
                'Item' => $orden['Number']
              );
            array_push($ordenesTest,$no);
        }
    }
    }
    return $ordenesTest;
}
```

json

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://test.com",
  "value": [
    {
      "Document_ID": "CO02472",
      "Sourcing_Location": "T090",
      "Number": "Ready"
     
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Con el JSON que muestras en la pregunta no hay problema, el código funciona. El error debe ocurrir en casos en que la petición cURL falla o trae otro tipo de información. Convendría que implementes control de errores en tu petición cURL y que depures la respuesta. Algo así: `$data=curl_exec($curl); if ( curl_errno($curl) ) {$msg=sprintf( "<b>Error</b>:%s<hr />",curl_error($curl) ); $data=json_encode( array( "error"=>$msg) ); } curl_close($curl); $json=json_decode($data); var_dump($json);` [Revisa aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/511852/29967) para más detalles.

Comment: Exacto el json viene bien, solo que tira ese error, revisare con lo que comentas

Comment: Aparte de eso que comenta @A.Cedano, no entiendo porque haces dos bucles anidados iguales con esto: `foreach($ordenes as $orden){`... con uno es suficiente. Ahora te funciona bien porque solo tienes un elemento dentro del array `value`, pero a la que tengas dos a más el resultado se repetirá tantas veces como elementos tengas en $ordenes.

Comment: al consumir la api me lo trae como NULL

Comment: Tendras que revisar esa llamada a la API pues, mírate bien sus instrucciones (no lo entiendo, creo que antes si que te traía datos, revisa los cambios que hayas podido hacer en las llamadas a CURL a ver si alguno te está provocando ese retorno NULL)