# curl PHP Bearer Token Auth Error 401

Tags: php, curl, postman

estoy realizando una petición con curl pero el resultado es curl_error: The requested URL returned error: 401 al realizar la misma petición desde POSTMAN funciona correctamente, este es el código que estoy usando.

```
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . str_replace( '"', '', $token )
);
$ch = curl_init( $server );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data2 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
$resp = curl_exec( $ch );
```

La respuesta en POSTMAN al consumir el servicio que implementé es:
[image: Respuesta en POSTMAN]

El API al que me intento conectar es diseñado por una empresa.

Comment: COnsidera la posibilidad de [edit] tu pregunta y ampliar el mensaje de error. HTTP 401 es unauthorized y no sabemos si se debe a algún problema de CORS, configuración, encabezados,...

Comment: Sería bueno saber que API estas utilizando. Seguramente el motivo del error esta documentado.

Comment: Cuando usas `cURL` puedes verificar el error mediando [`curl_errno()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-errno.php)
. [Aquí un código de ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/511852/29967).

Comment: @Marcos La API privada que desarrolló una empresa.

Comment: @A.Cedano El errorno es 22

Comment: @NelsonHernandez, eso quiere decir que no esta documentada?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si tengo la documentación, pero me dice que debo enviar el token que se genera con otro método y al realizar la prueba desde POSTMAN funciona si problemas.