# Error al pasar Json en array

Tags: php, json, api

Estoy trabajando sobre la api de [Agromonitoring](https://agromonitoring.com/api/polygons#create) y estoy intentando crear un polígono. El problema que tengo es que no se crea el polígono y tampoco me arroja ningún error. Muestro como lo estoy trabajando en base a la documentación:

cuerpo (BODY OF API REQUEST)

```
{
   "name":"Polygon Sample",
   "geo_json":{
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{

   },
   "geometry":{
     "type":"Polygon",
     "coordinates":[
        [
           [-121.1958,37.6683],
           [-121.1779,37.6687],
           [-121.1773,37.6792],
           [-121.1958,37.6792],
           [-121.1958,37.6683]
        ]
     ]
  }
  }
}
```

crear_poligino.php

```
// Crear nuevo polygono

$key = "c1133a63ae219a2cdf3e2367c8084869"; // lave de prueba

$new_polygon = 'http://api.agromonitoring.com/agro/1.0/polygons?appid='.$key;

$ch = curl_init($new_polygon);

$data = array(
    "name" => "pruebaUno",
    "geo_json" => {
        "type" => "Feature",
        "properties" => {},
        "geometry" => {
            "type" => "Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
                [
                    [-131.1958,37.6683],
                    [-131.1779,37.6687],
                    [-141.1773,37.6792],
                    [-141.1958,37.6792],
                    [-121.1958,37.6683]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
);

$send = json_encode(array("name" => $data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $send);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Hola en donde muestras el resultado??? $res no es implementado en ningun lado... por lo que veo...

Comment: claro.. ahí hice el cambio, solo `curl_exec($ch);`, pero tampoco me envía nada

Comment: No estoy seguro pero, en la linea `$send = json_enconde(array("name" => "data));` No sería suficiente con colocarlo de esta manera `$send = json_encode($data, TRUE)`

Comment: @Sebastian curl_exec($ch); envia la informacion al api no hace mas nada donde se supone que debe de pintarce el $res?

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($res);`? ¿Qué hay del manejo de errores, por si la petición falla: no conexión, API no disponible, problemas de red, etc? La *programación optimista* es un verdadero problema, sé pesimista cuando programes, pues algo puede salir mal y parte de la programación es afrontar eso que salga mal (manejo de errores). En peticiones curl es muy simple controlar los errores, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/511852/29967).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

de esta forma debería funcionar... has la prueba y dime

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.agromonitoring.com/agro/1.0/polygons?appid='.$key,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
   "name":"pruebaUno",
   "geo_json":{
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{

      },
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Polygon",
         "coordinates":[
            [
               [-131.1958,37.6683],
               [-131.1779,37.6687],
               [-141.1773,37.6792],
               [-141.1958,37.6792],
               [-121.1958,37.6683]
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$res = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $res;
```